# how to grep string at the begining of each line in a file

Tags: file, unix

I want to grep string at the begining of each line.
I have a file

Dave796, Cas79

Roger235, 40cad

689David, Pui22

697Lisa, Nas69

i want it like this

Dave796

Roger235

689 David

697Lisa

Comment: As a side note, your title was kinda misleading.  It looks like you wanted to *extract* strings at the beginning of each line.  To "grep" is to select some lines matching a pattern -- but maybe not select other lines.  So `grep "Dave" inputfile` would select lines containing the word `Dave`, or  `grep "^Dave" inputfile` would select lines which have the word `Dave` at the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 0):

Different solutions, easiest in your example data is

```
cut -d"," -f1 filename
```